# NodeJS csv data dump into s3 object

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm a beginner with AWS, JavaScript and I'm trying to get data from an oracle database using the following code in a AWS Lambda function.

```
 let conn = await this.getConnection(userName, password, connectString);
 let results = await conn.execute(query, {}, {});
 let data = results.rows.map(el => `${el}`);
 console.log(data);
```

which gives me the following output on the console

```
[ "TEST_SESSION_0,121,High,Warning,7",
"TEST_SESSION_2,122,High,Error,11",
"TEST_SESSION_3,123,Low,Error,431,
"TEST_SESSION_4, ASMT_,103,Low,Fatal,10" ]
```

Now, my goal is to convert this output into CSV data stream and then upload into S3 bucket object output.csv for further processing. i tried below to convert into 
CSV but having issue to connect it back to S3 using AWS SDK and required NPM modules, when i test the below code i dont get any error but at the same time dont see 
data getting uploaded to S3. not sure where i'm doing wrong, appreciate any help..

```
stringify(results.rows, function(err, output){
  if(err){
    console.log('some error occured '+ err);
  } else {
     console.log(output); //gives me below output
//TEST_SESSION_0,121,High,Warning,7
//TEST_SESSION_2,122,High,Error,11
//TEST_SESSION_3,123,Low,Error,431
//TEST_SESSION_4, ASMT_,103,Low,Fatal,10
```

below code is to take CSV output to upload to S3 object

```
     var param = {
       Bucket: 'Test-Bucket',
       Key: 'output.csv',
      Body: new Buffer(fs.createWriteStream(output)) //can i pass the csv data that i captured above in "output"?
      };  
    s3bucket.putObject(param, function(err, output){
   if(err) console.log(err);
  else console.log(output);
});
}
})
```

Comment: Can I know if what are you trying to achieve via this?

Answer (score 3):

I would start by separating out the code for the S3 upload and working on that part by itself - trying to get it to create a file in the bucket containing the text from a string.

The `putObject` function expects a `Buffer` as the `Body` param. To construct this from a string you can use the [`Buffer.from`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_from_string_encoding) method:

```js
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

var output = 'This is a test';
var myBody = Buffer.from(output);

var param = {
  Bucket: 'Test-Bucket',
  Key: 'output.csv',
  Body: myBody
};

var s3bucket = new AWS.S3({ signatureVersion: 'v2' });
s3bucket.putObject(param, function(err, output) {
  if(err) {
    console.error(err);
  } else {
    console.log(output)
  }
});
```

Once you have that part working perfectly, plug it into the other code and change `output` to be the contents of the CSV file.

**NB**  you will need the following environment variables set:

- AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
- AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY

Comment: Are you initialising the `s3bucket` var? I will update my code with an example of this.

Comment: actually, the problem was since i'm testing the Lambda locally on my PC i didn't update the env variable that will have 'output.csv' and that is the reason i was getting  bucket undefined error. i was able to test it successfully after making that change. thank you so much!!